# iframe-resizer js library: moveToAnchor from parent page

Tags: iframe-resizer

How can I scroll to a certain anchor tag inside the IFrame page?

Using the ingenious Iframe-Resizier Library by David J. Bradshaw
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer
I’m including an IFrame with a lot of content (=long page) inside the outer page. So if I link to the page, then much of the content isn't visible on the first screen and under certain circumstances I would like to jump to a specific anchor tag further down in the iframe.

```
<html>
    <a href=“outer-page.html#somewhere_name” />
</html>
```

seems not to work

I am using "inPageLinks: true" like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    iFrameResize({
        heightCalculationMethod: 'lowestElement',
        inPageLinks: true
</script>
```

My question now is: How can I make the outer page scroll down to a certain anchor tag without the need to implement something new inside the iframe page? The anchor tag in this case is located inside the IFrame page.

When I include the IFrame page like

```
<html>
    <iframe id=“strytl” src=“iframe-page.html#somewhere_name”></iframe
</html>
```

Then the (re)sizing of the IFrame seems not to work perfectly and contents at the top of the iframe are getting cut off.

But with moveToAnchor it works perfectly from inside the IFrame and the page is magically scrolling down to the anchor tag. So in the iframe page I can call:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    parentIFrame.moveToAnchor('somewhere_name’);
</script>
```

But how can I trigger this from the parent page?

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $('iframe#strytl').iFrameResize({moveToAnchor: 'somwhere_name'});
</script>
```

results in this error:

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
   [iFrameSizer][Host page: strytl] Ignored iFrame, already setup.and
</script>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    iFrameResize({
        heightCalculationMethod: 'lowestElement',
        inPageLinks: true,
        moveToAnchor: 'somewhere_name'});
</script>
```

seems to have no effect at all.

(In this case the outer page and the iframe have different server names.)

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
    var myFrm = document.getElementById('strytl');
    var myCw  = myFrm.contentWindow;
    myCw.parentIFrame.moveToAnchor(‘somewhere_name’);
</script>
```

result:

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
   Error: Permission denied to access property “parentIFrame"
</script>
```

Can I jump to an anchor in the iframe from the outer page at all?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    iFrameResize({
        heightCalculationMethod : 'lowestElement',
        inPageLinks             : true,
        initCallback            : function (iFrame){
            iFrame.iFrameResizer.moveToAnchor('someAnchor');
        }
     });
</script>
```